# Won't sum table column jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, sum

I have a dynamically created table and I need to sum the second column of the table. I keep getting 0 as the sum. 
Am I doing something wrong?

This is the function that's being called upon clicking a sum button, after the table has been created.

```
 function bukkake(){



    var sum = 0;
    $('.teedee td').eq(1).each(function(){
    sum += $(this).val();
    });
    $('#sum_result').append("The sum is: " + sum)



 }
```

This is the part of the code that creates the table:

```
$.getJSON("nutritional_value.php?value=" + encodeURI(value), function (data) {
var ttr = $("<tr />");   
$.each(data, function(k, v){
var store_1 = v * (parseFloat(uneseno, 10) / 100);
var xstore_1 = store_1.toFixed(2);

$("<td class='teedee'></td>").text(k=='name' ? v : xstore_1).appendTo(ttr);



 });

 $("#tejbl").append(ttr);
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Firstly you are using the wrong selector**

```
  $('.teedee td').eq(1).each(function(){ // You are trying to select
                                         // a td inside a class
```

supposed to be

```
$('td.teedee').eq(1).each(function(){  // But td is the one with the class
```

**Second**

A `td` does not have the property called `.val()`

use `.text()` instead if you want to target the text inside it

**Third**

```
$('td.teedee').eq(1) // Targets only 1 element with index 1
```

**Fourth**

Use `parseInt` to convert it to a number.

```
sum += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
```

Otherwise you would technically be appending strings instead. So first convert it to a number and then add.

### **Edit..**

First `parse the text` and check if it is not a number

```
var sum = 0;
$('tr').each(function() {
    $('td.teedee', this).eq(1).each(function () {
       var value = parseInt($(this).text(), 10);

       sum += isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    });
 });
$('#sum_result').append("The sum is: " + sum)
```

Comment: Thanks I learned something now, but now I get NaN as the result

Comment: The text() fixed the problem, but now it just displays the value from the first row. If I add more rows it just shows the value of the second column of the first row, instead of the second column of all the rows

Comment: @Filkatron.. You are trying to fetch the index of the `td` in respect to other `td's` . So that will be only one returned ..  So instead you need to check for that inside each row.. Check the edited code

Comment: @Filkatron.. Glad to have helped :)